# Continuum limit of a weighted mean

Tags: limits

I have already looked on Mathematics.SE for possible use of continuum limit but I did not find any question that helped me.

I try to find the limit of the following expression of a weighted mean of a series of $\rho_{i}$

Here is the expression ;

$$x\left(t\right)=\frac{\sum_{i}^{N}a_{i}\left(\omega_{i}e^{-\rho_{i}t}\right)^{\frac{1}{\eta}}}{\sum_{i}^{N}\left(\omega_{i}e^{-\rho_{i}t}\right)^{\frac{1}{\eta}}}$$

where $\omega$ is the weight for each $a$ and $t$ stands for time and $\eta$ is arbitrary constant term.

and let's say for $\omega_{i}\rightarrow a^{k-1}e^{-\frac{a}{\theta}}$ which is so-called Gamma distribution, where $k$ and $\omega$ are shape and scale parameters.

Conceptually, I have understood that continuum limit is the case where $N\rightarrow\infty$ and we should approximate the term by a continuum, which is probably an integral but I can not figure out how to find the continuum limit of this expression.

PS. The question comes from the following economics paper (page 14, equation 37)

: http://www.nber.org/papers/w18999.pdf

Comment: First of all, I assume that $\omega_i$ depends on $a_i$ rather than $a$. Second, what limit are you seeking? $N\to\infty$? Then you need to somehow describe/specify $a_i$ and $\rho)i$. I don't seem any "continuous limit" as of now.